# How to perform these two conversions from a symmetric metric

Tags: matrices, differential-geometry, coordinate-systems, tensors, general-relativity

Suppose in Cartesian coordinate system a Minkowski metric for flat spacetime can be written as :
 $$ ds^2 = a^2 (t)[-(1 + 2ψ(t,x,y,z))dt^2 - 2B_idx^idt + (1 - 2ψ(t,x,y,z))dx^{(i)2}] $$
This is a symmetric metric where x^i is comoving Cartesian coordinates. How can I produce pseudo orthonormal frame for this metric? For that case, what will be the components of this metric in the orthonormal frame?

Again, how can I convert the orthonormal frame to the general frame of spacetime?

Comment: You may apply the Gram-Schmidt process pointwise, as described in [page 9 here](https://www.asc.ohio-state.edu/terekcouto.1/texts/MAT6702_OSU-USP19_notes.pdf). Once this frame has been obtained, you may consider the dual coframe $(\theta^0, \theta^1,\theta^2, \theta^3)$ with $\theta^0$ dual to the timelike vector obtained via the GS-process -- then $${\rm d}s^2 = -\theta^0\otimes \theta^0 + \theta^1\otimes \theta^1 + \theta^2\otimes \theta^2 + \theta^3\otimes \theta^3.$$

Comment: Thanks a lot @Ivo Terek. I have managed this.